# Skype Internet Telephony

Tags: uninstall, skype

Skype Internet Telephony is installed on computer. It no longer works when I check computer says it is up to date.   I get message on phone that says call won't go thru because Skype is not up to date on computer.
I want to uninstall Skype Internet Telephony. It has a remove button that does nothing. When I checked computer couldn't find Skype package.  What I do have is a lot of "skype -bin:i386" files.
How can I remove Skype Internet Telephony and use version downloaded from Skype website?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge skype-bin` and the install the new package you downloaded from the Skype site, with `sudo dpkg -i newskype.deb` (where *newskype.deb* is the filename of the package you downloaded.

Comment: This is what I get:   
E: Unable to locate package skype-bini386
rogers:.-$ dpkg -s skype
Package: skype
Status: install ok tnstal.1.ed
Priority: extra
Section: partner/net
Installed-Size: 61
Maintainer: Steve Langasek <steve.1.angasekcanonical .con>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 4.3.8.37-Oubuntue.12.64.1
Depends: skype-bin
Description: client for Skype VOIP and Instant messaging service
Skype Is software that enables the worlds conversations. Millions of
Individuals and businesses use Skype to make free video and voice calls,
send Instant messages and sh

Comment: I left off i386 and it worked. Thanks